# Unable to login after adding ReCaptacha without API key

Tags: login, captcha

I was try to add recaptcha but accidently I got logged out and now I can't loogin to my wordpress. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: So what happens when you enter your username and password? Do you have shell or database access and already googled for how to disable plugins using wp-cli or directly in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you added code somewhere to enable the reCAPTCHA, then use your hosting File Manager (or a FTP CLient - I like WinSCP) and remove (or comment out) that code.

If you added the reCAPTCHA with a plugin, use File Manager/FTP to rename that plugin's folder, found in the wp_content/plugins folder of your site. That will temporarily disable the plugin from enabling the reCAPTCHA.

Once you have logged in, then find a better reCAPTCHA login plugin, perhaps. It looks as if that plugin you are using (assuming it's a plugin) doesn't recover gracefully from bad settings.